# Solve the equation below for all m and n which are positive integers

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find all positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that
$$m^2+2\cdot 3^n=m(2^{n+1}-1).$$

Comment: Fist thought: Take modulo $m$ on both sides, and you see that $2 \times 3^n \equiv 0 \mod{m}$. This should filter out quite much ...

Comment: I mean I got that, and I know that m is either a power of 3 or 2 multiplied by a power of 3 but I am not sure of how to continue from there.